# Exception not being handled by ErrorHanldeAttribute or OnException method in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, exception

I am trying to implement a global exception handling technique to avoid using try/catch blocks on every action of my controllers but my application crashes before the overridden OnException method or the ErrorHandleAttribute are reached.

Here is a simplified testing code:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception Test");
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null || filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        var message = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

and in Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"/>
```

If I set a break point on the 'throw' line and try to access /Home/Test my application will crash and both OnException method and the HandleErrorAttribute will be reached only after that.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Demystifying ASP.NET MVC 5 Error Pages and Error Logging](https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging)

Comment: @NightOwl888 Great article! I tried implementing the last four methods described there (as the first two are the ones I originally had) but I didn't succeed. My application will crash before any of them are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the `HandleError` filter.

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute{View = "Error"});
```

Comment: It didn´t work. I put that line in App_Start/FilterConfig.cs and registered in Global.asax with FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); but my application still crashes.